# How to solve typeError, mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm getting typeError for the following code. The data array is created before this function seedDB.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Here is the code:

```
function seedDB() {
   Campground.deleteMany({}, function(err, res){
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("removed campgrounds");
        }
        data.forEach(function(seed) {
        Campground.create(seed, function(err, campground) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log("added a new campground");
                Comment.create(
                    {
                        text: "this place is great",
                        author: "Homer"
                    }, function(err, comment) {
                        if(err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        } else {
 //it is this line here....=>
                            campground.comments.push(comment);
                            campground.save();
                            console.log("created new comment");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because either campground does not contain the key `comments` or the value of the `comments` is not an array. Log campground before `campground.comments.push(comment)` to check whether the 'comments' in campground is defined or not.

Comment: Solved it. Thank you :)

Comment: No problem!! :)